# Check if a process in multiprocessing.Pool has crashed

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, multiprocessing

I'm running some code using an external C library that very rarely crashes. I've wrapped this code using a `multiprocessing.Pool` to run it in parallel. I'd like to be able to detect if one of the processes in the pool has segfaulted. From [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327211/python-multiprocessing-pool-with-processes-that-crash) it sounds like I need to reimplement the pool using `multiprocessing.Process` in such a way that I can check the `is_alive()` but I'm not sure how to do that.

For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def fn(arg):
    if arg == 4:
        # this should segfault
        # http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-return-sigsegv
        import ctypes;ctypes.string_at(0)

    time.sleep(2)    
    return arg**2

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    inputs = range(10)
    results = pool.map_async(fn, inputs)

    while True:
        if results.ready():
            break

        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "status: still running..."

        # ... some async code ...
        # detect failed process here?

    outputs = results.get()

    print outputs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How could I re-write this to detect the segfault? (Also, I tried running it with python 3.5.0 and it didn't seem to raise an exception as suggested in that other question.)

Answer (score 0):

pool._pool is the list of processes, as multiprocessing.Process objects.

you can check their return codes

```
pool._pool[0].return_code
```

see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions

### EDIT AFTER COMMENTS

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def fn(arg):
    if arg == 4:
        # this should segfault
        # http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-return-sigsegv
        #pass
        import ctypes;ctypes.string_at(0)

    time.sleep(1)
    return (arg, arg**2)

def main():
    MAX_TOTAL_DURATION = 40
    MAX_TASK_DURATION = 10
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    inputs = range(10)
    start_time = time.time()
    results_iterator = pool.imap_unordered(fn, inputs, 1)
    got_result_for = []
    while len(got_result_for) < len(inputs) and (time.time() - start_time) < MAX_TOTAL_DURATION:
        try:
            argument, result = results_iterator.next(MAX_TASK_DURATION)
            got_result_for.append(argument)
            print("status: got results for: " + str(got_result_for))
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
            print("one of the tasks timeouted")

    if len(got_result_for) < len(inputs):
        print("missing results: " + str(set(inputs).difference(set(got_result_for))))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `pool` -- all processes return `True` for `is_alive()` and have `exitcode` equal to `None` (using python 2.7.10 or 3.5.0); note that both `is_alive()` is False and `exitcode` is `-11` when using Process directly

Comment: Just checked -- would have worked with python 2.6 but doesn't with newer versions

Comment: ah right, the segfaulted process probably gets restarted by the pool :(

Comment: as far as i understand multiprocessing source code (http://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.0/pool_8py_source.html), your case means that line 119 segfaults. when that happens, the job has been previously taken off the "inputs" queue, but no result, not even an exception can be put on the output queue. so you can probably detect that case by  exploring the results to determinate which input was not taken in account.

Comment: ...though in that case I wouldn't know that the process died rather than finished because it never returns `ready()`, right? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you. If it works for you, could you post some example code?

Comment: i posted a workaround, but really it should be the Pool's job to find about the segfault process and notify the user about it. maybe you can try to write about it on python-dev mailing list ?